# Treeview moves after click on Combobox with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, treeview

I have developped a app in Python (tested with 3.8 and 3.9 on Windows 10) with Tkinter. I am using a Combobox and a Treeview. I want to change dynamically the width of dropdown listbox and I could do it by changing the style of TCombobox with the parameter **postoffset**.

However, **everytime I click on the Combobox, the table next to it moves and extends its width by itself**. I really don't know where this problem comes from.

I have created a simple code so that you can reproduce the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

def combo_configure(event, style):
    combo = event.widget
    long = max(combo.cget('values'), key=len)
    font = tkfont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=10)
    width = max(0,font.measure(long.strip() + '0') - combo.winfo_width())
    style.configure('TCombobox', postoffset=(0,0,width,0))

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("850x250")
style = ttk.Style()

f = tk.Frame(win)
f.configure(bg="black")
f.pack()

combo = ttk.Combobox(f, style="TCombobox", values=["It's a test on Combobox style."], width=10)
combo.bind('<ButtonPress>', lambda e : combo_configure(e, style))
combo.pack(side="left")

tree = ttk.Treeview(f, column=["Column 1"], show='headings', height=10)
tree.heading(0, text="Column 1")
tree.column(0, anchor=tk.CENTER, width=125)
tree.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code failed to run due to `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` on the line `tree.heading(i, text="Column 1")`.

Comment: Sorry I have changed it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue on my Windows 10 with Python 3.10.2.

Comment: Indeed, I had tested with 3.8 and 3.9. I updated python to 3.10.2 and the problem is gone. Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't reproduce it on 3.8 but on Linux :) So it may also depends on system.